# How to use SQLite PRAGMA threads = X ; into C++ code

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am working on a project in C/C++ where i need to speed up some SQLite queries.

Which in my computer takes about 4.5 seconds and returns 214.000 rows.

One idea i had is to use:

```
PRAGMA threads = 2;
```

before the query.

I tried it at the sqlitebrowser and the query took 2 seconds which is a nice improvement in my case.

The question is: how i can do the same inside my C++ code?
I concatenated the query after the PRAGMA but i didn't got any improvement.

I also tried `sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_WORKER_THREADS,4);` with no luck.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the queries that are too slow, and your database schema.  Maybe there is a different approach that would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do that, because these data are private and my company owns them. We are quite sure that the query is OK and it does go better using PRAGMA threads. I just cannot figure out how to use it in C/C++.

Comment: It's very likely that the cause of your problem has nothing to do with threads, but without more information, I don't think anyone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

A PRAGMA statement is a statement like any other SQL statement, just execute it (separately).

Comment: You might have a wrong SQLite version, or compiled it wrong, or not executed the PRAGMA correctly, or not in the correct connection.